# BizTalk 2010 Dynamic FTP Send Port Output Directory and File Name Issue

Tags: dynamic, ftp, filenames, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a rather complex requirement - that I have to drop a very specifically named file in an FTP location, and the trick here is that I would often have to drop it into a new location and with a new file name each time (both directory name and file name depending on the year, month, date and time). Obviously, for this purpose I chose to use a Dynamic Send Port, which I have configured using a MessageAssignment Shape.

A file will be generated each day. I need to drop it in a remote location in this form:
**sample-servername-stage/default/file/ftp/PaymentReports/YYYY/MM_[MonthName]/PaymentReportYYYYMMDD_HHMISS**

For example, for a file posted on **March, 2 2016 at 6:45pm**, we would have:

**sample-servername-stage/default/file/ftp/PaymentReports/2016/03_March/PaymentReport20160302_184500**

Here's the code I have in the MessageAssignment Shape:

```
FTPSendPort1(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address) = "ftp://sample-servername-stage:721";
FTPSendPort1(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.TransportType) = "FTP";

Output(FTP.CommandLogFileName) =  "D:\\BiztalkLogs\\FTPLog\\DynamicFTPLog.txt";
Output(FTP.UserName) =  "sampleUsername";
Output(FTP.Password) =  "samplePassword";
Output(FTP.BeforePut) = "MKD " + Variable_1 + ";CWD " + Variable_1;
```

FTPSendport1 - name of the Dynamic Send Port.

Output - name of the Output message.

Variable_1 - variable where I will store the directory name to be created.

Here are the biggest issues:

1. I need to check if a directory already exists - the year, then navigate in and check if the month already exists. If they exist I simply go in there and drop the file. If not, I create it and drop the file in there.
2. I need to name the file with the date time specifics in the format shown above. In addition to the code shown above, I have tried a number of things including setting `FILE.ReceivedFileName`,  `FTP.ReceivedFileName` properties etc. Nothing seems to work. This may be because I cannot use the macro `%SourceFileName%` anywhere.  Because of this it keeps dropping the file into the location with a GUID name instead of the one I set. It behaves as though it completely skips/overlooks the command where I set the file name.

I'm thoroughly confused at this point. I'm not sure of how I can mix checking conditions (if the folders already exist etc.) with FTP commands, and especially not sure of how to do this within an orchestration.

Comment: Have you tried setting the fileMask property to the file name you want?    Does the MKD actually cause an error if it already exists?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf There is no option to set the fileMask property when specifying the parameters for the dynamic FTP send port within the orchestration. At least, if there is, I don't know how to access it. There is a property called FTP.ReceivedFileName and that doesn't work either.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to do the directory creation separate from the adapter.  FTP.ReceivedFileName should work to set the file name, but won't create directories for you if they don't already exist.  If possible, I'd set this up as a job on the destination server - every night at midnight (or 11:59) it creates the new directory for the day.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bc1fec47-2bc8-4bf9-b0fc-437dc5002ced/biztalk-2010-ftp-adapter-create-folder-dynamically-to-drop-file-to?forum=biztalkgeneral

Comment: Is there any way you can get the owner of that FTP site to simplify their structure?  That's really complicated and whenever I encounter something like this there's really no benefit even on their side, meaning, that's just they way it's done for no reason anyone knows.

Answer (score 2):

The file naming is done in the address property where you provide the FTP URL. In fact you can even use macros in there. Try that:

```
FTPSendPort1(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address) = "ftp://sample-servername-stage:721/SomeFolder/SomeFileName_%datetime%.xml"
```

For you other problem of checking if folders exists on the FTP and creating them, I think you'll have to write a custom pipeline component.